# How to update multiple columns with a single statment

Tags: sqlite

I'm updating a series of columns `Country1`, `Country2`... `Country 9` based on a comma delimited string of country names in column `Country` and the process is taking quite some time:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country1 = returnCountryName(Country,0) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country2 = returnCountryName(Country,1) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country3 = returnCountryName(Country,2) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country4 = returnCountryName(Country,3) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country5 = returnCountryName(Country,4) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country6 = returnCountryName(Country,5) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country7 = returnCountryName(Country,6) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country8 = returnCountryName(Country,7) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country9 = returnCountryName(Country,8) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
cur.execute("UPDATE t SET Country10 = returnCountryName(Country,9) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;")
```

Would it be faster to use one statment, and how? Something like....

```
cur.execute("UPDATE t 
    SET Country1 = returnCountryName(Country,0) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
    SET Country2 = returnCountryName(Country,1) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
    SET Country3 = returnCountryName(Country,2) WHERE Country IS NOT NULL
    ...
    ;")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is like so:

```
UPDATE t 
SET Country1 = returnCountryName(Country,0),
    Country2 = returnCountryName(Country,1),
    Country3 = returnCountryName(Country,2),
    ...
    Country10 = returnCountryName(Country,9)
WHERE Country IS NOT NULL;
```

This should be also faster than doing multiple queries as the it will scan the table and rewrite the rows only once.

Comment: I asked another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691052/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-where-syntax-error) based on a bug I'm getting trying to implement your solution

Comment: One last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691218/how-to-update-multiple-columns-with-a-single-statement-with-multiple-conditions) if you would like to answer it