# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to update a series of columns Country1, Country2... Country 9 based on a comma delimited string of country names in column Country. I've programmed a single statement to accomplish this task.

```
cur.execute("\
            UPDATE t \
            SET Country1 = returnCountryName(Country,0),\
                Country2 = returnCountryName(Country,1),\
                Country3 = returnCountryName(Country,2),\
                Country4 = returnCountryName(Country,3),\
                Country5 = returnCountryName(Country,4),\
                Country6 = returnCountryName(Country,5),\
                Country7 = returnCountryName(Country,6),\
                Country8 = returnCountryName(Country,7),\
                Country9 = returnCountryName(Country,8),\
                Country10 = returnCountryName(Country,9),\
            WHERE Country IS NOT NULL\
            ;")
```

Howerver, I am getting the error

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the comma from the last assignment:

```
Country10 = returnCountryName(Country,9),\
```

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39690916/6776093) to your original question

Comment: wow, I looked and looked for that last comma and didn't see it... maybe I need my glasses