# How to update multiple columns with a single statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sqlite

I want to update a series of columns `Country1`, `Country2`... `Country 9` based on a comma delimited string of country names in column Country. I have done so with the following statment:

```
cur.execute("\
            UPDATE t \
            SET Country1 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,0),\
                Country2 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,1),\
                ...
                Country10 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,9),\
            WHERE Country IS NOT NULL\
            ;")
```

I also have a column named `Genre` in my tabe. Now I would like to update columns `Genre1`, `Genre2`... `Genre9` in the same statment. I think the statment would look something like:

```
cur.execute("\
                UPDATE t \
                SET Country1 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,0), Genre1 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Genre,0)\
                    Country2 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,1), Genre2 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Genre,1)\
                    ...
                    Country10 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,9), Genre10 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Genre,9)\
                WHERE Country IS NOT NULL\
                AND Genre IS NOT NULL
                ;")
```

Is the statement correct?

Comment: This is horrible table design. Can you change that?

Comment: Not sure if I can, why is it so horrible?

Comment: Did you mean `Genre1 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Genre,0)` instead of `Genre1 = returnCommaDelimitedValue(Country,0)`?

Comment: @redneb Yeah thanks, and why do people think my table design is so horrible?

Comment: Because it is ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run 2 separate `update` queries. The problem is that `Country` can be null independently of `Genre`. So however you combine the conditions `Country IS NOT NULL` and `Genre IS NOT NULL` in the `where` clause of the query, you will miss some columns that could have been updated, or you will update some columns with `null` values.

Now, I haven't seen the implementation of `returnCommaDelimitedValue`. It is possible that it returns `null` when the string argument is `null`. In that case, you might consider remove the `where` clause completely and update the `countryN` and `genreN` columns in the same query. In that case, if `Country` is `null`, this will also make `Country1` null, so this might be something that you want. If almost all rows have a non-`null` `Country` and `Genre`, this approach might be faster.

Comment: Yes, there is a `Genre` column. Thanks for point out that ambiguity. Honestly, I'm not sure if I need `Genre IS NOT NULL` condition but considering the `returnCommaDelimitedValue(String, integer)` takes in a String as a parameter, I thought I might obviate a potential bug if the `Genre` field is empty. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Country1, Country2, Country3... this is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). You're feeling the consequences of very poor table design. Don't feel too put out, this is a very common anti-pattern. Lists are difficult and very non-intuitive to work with in standard SQL. The whole mess is referred to as "normalization".

Lists are represented by [join tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in a [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)). One `t` has many countries. This is a very big topic to get into, but here's a sketch.

Instead of having Country1, Country2, Country3, etc... in whatever `t` is, I'm going to call it Thing, you'd have a table called ThingCountries to represent the list.

```
create table ThingCountries (
    ThingID integer references Thing(id),
    Country text
);
```

Each Country belonging to a Thing would be inserted into ThingCountries along with the ID of the thing.

```
# Do this in a loop
insert into ThingCountries (ThingID, Country) values (?, ?)
```

They'd be retrieved with a join by linking Thing.ID and ThingCountries.ThingID.

```
select ThingCountries.Country from Thing
join ThingCountries on Thing.ID = ThingCountries.ThingID
where Thing.ID = ?
```

By querying ThingCountries you can quickly find out which Things have a certain Country.

```
select ThingID from ThingCountries
where Country = ?
```

They can be removed with a simple delete.

```
delete from ThingCountries where ThingID = ? and Country = ?
```

There's no need to know how many Country columns there are. There's no gaps to be filled in. There's no limit to how many Countries a Thing can have.

---

Later on down the road you might want to store information about each country, like its name and abbreviation.  In which case you make a Country table.

```
create table Country (
    id integer primary key,
    name text not null,
    abbrev text not null
);
```

And then ThingCountries references Country by is id rather than storing the Country name.

```
create table ThingCountries (
    ThingID   integer references Thing(id),
    CountryID integer references Country(id)
);
```

Now you can store whatever information you want about each Country, and it protects against typos (because the Country has to exist in the Country table).

Do the same thing for Genre and your problem goes away.

It's a bit awkward, but that's how SQL does it. Best to get used to it. Alternatively some databases offer array types to make this simpler, like [Postgres arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).

More Reading:

- [Ten Common Database Design Mistakes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/) particularly "Ignoring Normalization"
- [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: This is mind bending, and will take me a while to digest. Thanks.

Comment: I would need to see a graphical representation of this concept to understand it.

Comment: So are you saying `ThingCountries` would have `ThingID` as column headers and country names as column values?

Comment: @the_prole Yes, it is mind bending. "Column headers" and "column values" are terms from spreadsheets. Instead use "column" and "row" when talking about SQL tables. ThingCountries has two columns: ThingID and the Country name. You might wind up with rows like "1, US", "1, UK", "1, ES", "2, US", "3, UK". This means Thing 1 has the countries US, UK, and ES. Thing 2 is just US. Thing 3 is just UK.

Comment: @the_prole Here's a SQLFiddle for you to play with. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/951ef/2

Comment: So I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697974/how-to-split-comma-delimited-values-into-multiple-rows-using-python?noredirect=1#comment66694803_39697974) is what I want?

Comment: @the_prole Looks about right, except their code has quoting and SQL injection vulnerabilities. I'll comment over there.